# live-server won't be installed globally on Mac BigSur

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install, npm-live-server

My fresh new Mac Air won't install `live-server` globally. It keeps throwing the same error after I factory reseted my Mac though.

```
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

I tried re-install again on `root` but it throws this error

```
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/var/root/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.17.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
+ live-server@1.2.1
```

How do I actually install `live-server` on my Mac globally?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is caused because the script doesn't have the permissions to access `/var`.

Have you tried installing with `sudo`?

```
sudo npm install -g live-server
```